# jquery to save $ value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to restore the `$` value after `jQuery.noConflict()`. How could I do this?

```
$ = 12 
$ = jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery.noConflict()
$ //undefined
```

I wish `$` will be 12 again.

Comment: I think you may be confused about how noConflict works.  noConflict will restore `$` back to what it was, before jQuery initialized.  Which is when the file was imported.  If you are changing the $ after that fact, that is past the point that jQuery has recorded what `$` was.

Comment: Well...you cannot. `$ = jQuery.noConflict()` will wipe the value. You can't just "go back" in what a variable held before. Not without resorting to using other variables for storage.

Comment: I don't think jQuery will do this for you: you'll have to store it in your own variable. Or why not use something else for the jQuery.noConflict, or use an anonymous function to keep that `$` in a new scope if you have to use `$`?

Comment: Yep.  As @Taplar has said, I am confused why the method-noConflict cannot restore $. Can we import jQuery again so that it can save $ ,although we have other methods to save the previous $ value such as what Rup has suggested?

Comment: The fact of the matter is that executing `$ = jQuery.noConflict()` doesn't even make sense.  The whole point of `noConflict` is to restore `$` back to what it was prior to jQuery initializing and taking it over.  But that statement causing jQuery to revert it, and then you assign it right back to the `$`, which makes it a pointless operation.